# PHP form does not send informations only from mobile devices

Tags: php, forms, mobile

(**See updates below**)

I have this pretty simple PHP contact form which work great on every browser. On submit, the process goes through `formaction.php`, which you see below and then validate the captcha, send the infos and redirect to the selected page.

My problem is that I realised last week that the form won't send anything when used from a mobile device, tested on iPhone 4S, 5S and Samsung SIII.

At first sight, I removed the `$recipient` variable, which was the last update I did to `formaction.php` and realised the problem wasn't there.

As I am new to PHP, I had this thought that maybe the head variables might not be recognized by some mobile devices, so I removed the `$POST[blablabla]` to write some core infos. Which hasn't work.

I searched a lot to find the differences between the mobile and web sending processes but still the issue is going on.

```
session_start();
if(isset($_POST["captcha"]) && 
   $_POST["captcha"]!="" && 
   $_SESSION["code"]==$_POST["captcha"])
{
    Header("Location: http://www.mysite.fake/thank" );

    $recipients = array('info' => 'info@mysite.fake', 
                        'ventes' => 'ventes@mysite.fake', 
                       'commandites' => 'commandites@mysite.fake'
                      );

    $to = $recipients[$_POST['sujet']];
    $head .= "From: ".$_POST['nom']." <".$_POST['courriel'].">\r\n";
    $head .= "X-Sender: <info@mysite.fake>\n";
    $head .= "X-Mailer: PHP\n";
    $head .= "Return-Path: <info@mysite.fake>\n";
    $head .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\n";

    $sujet = "Subject | ".$_POST['nom']." contacted you for ".$_POST['sujet'].".";
    $informations = "
    Hi, you received a new demand. \r\n
    Name: ".$_POST['nom']." \r\n
    Mail: ".$_POST['courriel']." \r\n
    Subject: ".$_POST['sujet']."\r\n
    Message: ".$_POST['texte']." \r\n";

    mail($to, $sujet ,$informations, $head); 
} else {
    Header("Location: http://www.mysite.fake/error" );
}
```

**Update:** After talking with @RiggsFolly, I verified the Apache logs and the request do reaches the server normally. So, everything works backend.. any ideas?

```
[10/Jan/2015:19:58:45 -0700] "GET /fr/contact HTTP/1.1" 200 3997 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 8_1_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0 Mobile/12B440 Safari/600.1.4"
[10/Jan/2015:19:58:45 -0700] "GET /fr/captcha/captcha.php HTTP/1.1" 200 588 "http://eragraff.com/fr/contact" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 8_1_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0 Mobile/12B440 Safari/600.1.4"
[10/Jan/2015:19:59:19 -0700] "POST /fr/formaction.php HTTP/1.1" 302 547 "http://eragraff.com/fr/contact" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 8_1_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0 Mobile/12B440 Safari/600.1.4"
[10/Jan/2015:19:59:22 -0700] "GET /fr/formthank HTTP/1.1" 301 522 "http://eragraff.com/fr/contact" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 8_1_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0 Mobile/12B440 Safari/600.1.4"
[10/Jan/2015:19:59:23 -0700] "GET /fr/formthank HTTP/1.1" 200 682 "http://eragraff.com/fr/contact" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 8_1_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0 Mobile/12B440 Safari/600.1.4"
[10/Jan/2015:19:59:26 -0700] "GET /fr/contact HTTP/1.1" 200 3997 "http://eragraff.com/fr/formthank" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 8_1_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0 Mobile/12B440 Safari/600.1.4"
[10/Jan/2015:19:59:26 -0700] "GET /fr/captcha/captcha.php HTTP/1.1" 200 609 "http://eragraff.com/fr/contact" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 8_1_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0 Mobile/12B440 Safari/600.1.4"
```

**Chrome desktop log**

```
184.xxx.xx.xx - - [10/Jan/2015:20:39:15 -0700] "POST /formaction.php HTTP/1.1" 302 430 "http://mysite.fake/contact" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36"
```

**Safari mobile log**

```
207.xx.xx.xxx - - [10/Jan/2015:20:28:29 -0700] "POST /formaction.php HTTP/1.1" 302 482 "http://mysite.fake/contact" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 8_1_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0 Mobile/12B440 Safari/600.1.4"
```

**Requests logs, verified with *Charles Proxy**

Here is the request;

```
POST /formaction.php HTTP/1.1
Host: mysite.fake
Content-Length: 141
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8,image/webp
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Origin: http://mysite.fake
Referer: http://mysite.fake/contact
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 8_1_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) CriOS/39.0.2171.50 Mobile/12B440 Safari/600.1.4
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: fr-FR,fr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Cookie: __utma=113777771.1205974649.1111957503.1428078344.1426693544.35; __utmz=113777771.1111957503.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); __utmc=113777771; PHPSESSID=brmpaudvr2rxxxxxxxxna0000; __utmb=113777771.3.10.1421093598
```

Here is the server response;

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Date: Mon, 12 Jan 2015 20:34:40 GMT
Server: Apache
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Location: http://mysite.fake/formthank
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 20
Content-Type: text/html
```

Comment: Dump the contents of `$_POST` when on desktop and then on mobile, see if there are any differences. And does it happen only on the mobile network, or also on Wi-Fi ? If it's the former, that's because mobile ISPs often put everyone behind a transparent HTTP proxy and it may mess with the request in such a way that it fails.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Daniel. Content from each other looks the same. But you brought something interesting..! I tried, for the first time, on a 3G network and I succeeded one time outta 5 (the first one) different tests to send the infos correctly. I do not see nothing strange in the logs between my 5 attemps..

Comment: I updated with the Apache log of the `$_POST` on desktop vs mobile. I see that `HTTP/1.1" 302 430`, the 430 changed for 482 on mobile. After a few search, I do not find any error code attribuated to 430 and 482. The 302 being a redirect (Am I right? lol)

Comment: I haven't been able to find anything conclusive about it, but check that the code after the `Header("Location: http://www.mysite.fake/thank" );` is actually always being executed. Try putting the header after the code to send the email.

Comment: Thanks @ChaimChaikin. I tried this morning and sadly ain't working. An header redirect is able to run the script after except with an `exit;` as long as it's in the `if`.

Comment: Is it normal that this request is made twice ? This one is the header redirect if captcha's validated (`Header("Location: http://www.mysite.fake/thank" );`)
`"GET /fr/formthank HTTP/1.1" 301 522` and 
`"GET /fr/formthank HTTP/1.1" 200 682`

Comment: @AndréDaniel, is there a known way for me to hardpush the request to execute although the proxy? I would like to do a few tests but you lost me at "Mobile ISP" lol

Comment: Could you please try a packet capture (with Wireshark or tcpdump) on the server to see exactly what the request from the mobile looks like ? Your logs don't show much difference and everything seems fine, both always return 302 which is correct; the value after that is either the amount of data sent or the time it took for the request to complete, so it's normal that they're not identical but they're irrelevant for this problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot @AndréDaniel for those explainations, pretty much clearer now. I will search a bit more about Wireshark packet captures to understand it well and I will be back to you with furter infos asap. Thank you for your time !

Comment: @AndréDaniel, please see the updated post, with the server request/response informations. Note that I used a program I already had, Charles Proxy. Let me know if you need something else for you to see.

Comment: @G.EGCB yeah but I said to do it while being on the mobile network, which means doing a packet capture server side. The problem doesn't appear on Wi-Fi, right ?

Comment: @AndréDaniel Sorry, my bad. Sadly, yeah, the problem happens on WiFi too.

Comment: @AndréDaniel I failed using Wireshark or tcpdump due to shared network accesses but I find out how to simulate 3G with Charles and I do not see differences in the request/response of formaction. Is the simulation as reliable? Idk.. but still the issue goes on WiFi tho.
Well, gotta say, thanks again for your time and help !!!

Comment: @G.EGCB simulation isn't reliable (it does only simulate reduced bandwidth/packet loss, not a nasty HTTP proxy some ISPs use) but it doesn't matter since it happens on WI-Fi as well.

Comment: @AndréDaniel haha good, thanks for the follow-up. I'll keep testing and searching about it ! Feel free if you got any further hints, you've been a grand help.

Comment: @G.EGCB I'm really not in the mood to do any testing right now, I'll try your code on my own devices tomorrow.

Comment: No stress, you don't have to do it tho, you already did a lot :) Feel free !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem was actually caused by a coincidence and had nothing to do with the device you submit the form from. The problem is that your code is setting the sender address to whatever email the user submitted in the form, and your mail server rejects that because the sender address obviously doesn't match with the credentials your script uses to log into the SMTP server.

Instead of spoofing the sender's address to the address the customer put in, use a sender address your server will accept like `contactform@yourdomain`, and set the `Reply-To` header to the customer's email, so you still keep all advantages of spoofing the sender's address (I assume it's for being able to reply to the customer directly by clicking "reply" in your mail client) while making the server happy because you're not spoofing anything. Here's an example :

```
$mail->From = "contactform@yourdomain"; // no sender spoofing so server is happy
$mail->addReplyTo("customer's email", "customer's name"); // reply button works
```

Also, your current code has some problems, no validation on data what-so-ever (I can submit empty values and your script will still attempt to send the mail), no error checking (you instantly redirect users to a success page even before attempting to send the mail) and email header injection (attackers can use your server to send spam to any address).

First I recommend you use [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) instead of `mail()`, it's a lot easier to work with, you don't have to manually build the header string and it's safe against email injection.

Here's a basic script I came up with, it's definitely not the prettiest code I've written but it does a good enough job at validation of the values and will throw meaningful errors if something is wrong :

```
session_start();

// iterate over all expected values and exit if any are missing or empty
foreach (["captcha", "sujet", "nom", "courriel", "texte"] as $value) {
    if (!isset($_POST[$value]) || empty($_POST[$value])) {
        die("Missing or empty value ".$value);
    }
}

// recipient array, used both for validation and mail sending
$recipients = ["info" => "info@...", "ventes" => "ventes@...", "commandites" => "..."];

// exit if the recipient's identified isn't valid
if (!in_array($_POST["sujet"], array_keys($recipients))) {
    die("Incorrect recipient");
}

// exit if the sender's email address isn't valid
if (!filter_var($_POST["courriel"], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    die("Incorrect sender email");
}

// check if the captcha's code was set previously
if (!isset($_SESSION["code"])) {
    // if not, ask the user to go back and see the captcha
    die("Missing code, go back and request the captcha image again");
} elseif ($_SESSION["code"] != $_POST["captcha"]) {
    // otherwise, check if the captcha is correct and exit if not
    die("Incorrect captcha, please try again");
}

// new mailer object
$mail = new PHPMailer;

// configure your SMTP server's details
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = "smtp.example.com";
$mail->Port = 25; // 587 for tls (STARTTLS), 465 for ssl

// if your server requires auth
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = "user@example.com";
$mail->Password = "secret";
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";

// here we make the actual email
$mail->From = "contactform@yourdomain";
$mail->FromName = $_POST["nom"];
$mail->addAddress($recipients[$_POST["sujet"]]);
$mail->addReplyTo($_POST["courriel"], $_POST["nom"]);
$mail->Subject = $_POST["sujet"];
$mail->Body = $_POST["texte"];

if ($mail->send()) {
    echo "Success !";
} else {
    echo "Something went wrong";
    echo "Error details :".$mail->ErrorInfo;
    // in production, hide the error details to not reveal potentially sensitive info
}
```

Comment: Wow thanks a lot for taking the time to do that, I'll definitely check that out right away ! I have a validation process on my form, on the contact.php file. Each value is required and `onSubmit`, goes through a `ValidateForm` JS code I wrote down which works pretty well. But yours looks clean, pretty much effective and safe. Infinite thanks, I'll update you with the results !

Comment: My editor returns there is an syntax error on line 4 (foreach) and line 11 ($recipients). First look, I don't know which but imma take a look and keep you updated !

Comment: @G.EGCB never rely on the client for validation; a malicious attacker will bypass that easily.

Comment: @G.EGCB strange, on PHP 5.6.4 there doesn't seem to be any syntax errors and it parses it successfully.

Comment: Aaah makes sense, my host's 5.4. I did a couple read for the last hour and I'll keep working on that. I will mark your answer as solved because I'm sure this will work perfectly and comes to my needs. I'll comment back if I'm wondering about a part of your answer. Anyways, infite thanks André !

Comment: @G.EGCB I'm pretty sure it has to do something with the arrays... first try to remove the array from the first foreach loop and define it as a variable, and then just reference that variable in the foreach. If it still doesn't work, try using the old and ugly `array(item, other item, etc)` syntax. Oh and don't forget to install PHPMailer and to include its autoloader file.

Comment: Thanks, I'll def try it, I read this way in the PHP Manual too. I'm sure this will work fine !

Comment: Hey @André Daniel, PHPMailer works super fine, I love it ! The only issue, is the same as this post thread, still does not work from mobile devices.. After a few tests, I realized that those lines `$mail->From = $_POST["courriel"];` are the problem. It works fine on desktop but calling a `POST` variable in the `$mail` does not work with mobiles. I tried calling the variable like `$courriel = $_POST["courriel"]` and `$mail = $courriel` but it does not work.. 3G, WiFi, logs looks similar, same issues particularities as first sight.

Comment: Oh, true that, thanks for the precision. Email has been sent !

Answer (score 0):

After troubleshooting my code, I realized an `$head` line was actually the problem.

This one in particular..

```
$head = "From: ".$_POST['nom']." <".$_POST['courriel'].">\n";
```

As soon as I tested removing `$head` from the `mail` line, I succeeded sending mail by mobile devices. So I took each line one by one and wrote core infos, which worked with the first one, the `From:`, where I wrote a core email address.

```
$head = "From: <info@mysite.fake>\n";
```

Well, problem solved, another problem up. Having variables in the `From:` was pretty cool because it fasten the reply to the users.

If someone knows why do those `$_POST` in the `$head` weren't assimilated by mobile devices or how can I implement them better, I'd be happy to know a little more on what happened.

Comment: Note that your code is still vulnerable to email header injection, and that there is no validation on the data.